# How to update an array within a map using Firestore functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an array within a map that I want to update using Firestore Functions. My data structure looks like this:

[image]

In this case, I want to update the shareRecordsWith array within the {uid} map.

I have been trying to use the following firestore functions but it's not working.

```
const recordsDict = {"uid": aboutUID, "accessType": accessType}
profilesRef.doc(uid).set({
    [uid]: {
        {'shareRecordsWith': admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(recordsDict)},
        {merge: true}
    }
});
```

**Is there a way to update an array within a map through Firestore Functions?**

**EDIT**: Based on the suggestions, I changed the function to

```
profilesRef.doc(uid).set({
    [`${uid}.shareRecordsWith`]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(recordsDict)
}, { merge: true })
```

Unfortunately, then it adds ${uid}.shareRecordsWith as a new field in the document instead of adding to the shareRecordsWith array within the {uid} map.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call out the entire path of the nested field as a single property.  You can do this by passing a [FieldPath](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldPath.html) object with [update()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#update), but it doesn't look like [set()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#set) supports this.

```
profilesRef.doc(uid).update(
    new admin.firestore.FieldPath(uid, "shareRecordsWith"),
    admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(recordsDict)
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's adding `${uid}.shareRecordsWith` as a new field in the document instead of adding to the shareRecordsWith array within the {uid} map. I've edited and attached a screenshot in my original post.

Comment: Looks like you will have to use update() with FieldPath.

Comment: Worked your solution after I took out the close bracket! Thank you so much!